# The conditions for affine transformations of ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The following is called the affine transformation, especially called congruent transformation when $λ = 1$, and I got the following expression based on the question

$$
  \begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} & = λ\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} e \\ f \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align*}
$$

Based on the given vectors,

$$
  r_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
      0 \\
      0 
    \end{pmatrix},
  r_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix},
  r_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 \\
      2
    \end{pmatrix},
  r_0^{'} = \begin{pmatrix}
      2 \\
      1
    \end{pmatrix},
  r_1^{'} = \begin{pmatrix}
      5 \\
      2
    \end{pmatrix},
  r_2^{'} = \begin{pmatrix}
      3 \\
      8
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I got $a = 3/\sqrt{10}, b = 1/\sqrt{10}, c = -1/\sqrt{10}, d = a = 3/\sqrt{10}, λ = \sqrt{10}, e = 2, f = 1$ respectively.

$$
  \begin{align*}
    \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} & = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align*}
$$

With two equations and $l,m,l',m'$ are positive real numbers,

$$
  (a) \dfrac{x^2}{l^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{m^2} = 1, \quad (b) \dfrac{x'^2}{l'^2} + \dfrac{y'^2}{m'^2} = 1
$$

The graph of equation $(a)$ and $(b)$ are called $F_a$ and $F_b$ respectively. Now, I would like to find the necessary and sufficient conditions for this affine transformation when the transformation exists if we transform from $F_a$ to $F_b$. (Note that there are $l > m, l < m, l = m, l^{'} > m^{'}, l^{'} = m^{'},  l^{'} < m^{'}$ cases)

Based on the transformation, I can write the equations as below,

$$
  \begin{align*}
    \begin{cases} x' = 3x - y + 2 \\ y' = x+3y + 1 \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
$$

Therefore, I tried as follows,

$$
  \begin{align*}
    &(3x-y+2)^2(m')^2 + (x+3y+1)^2(l')^2 \\
    & = (9x^2-6xy+12x+y^2-4y+4)(m')^2 + (x^2+6xy+2x+9y^2+6y+1)(l')^2 \\
    & = (9m'^2+l'^2)x^2 + (m'^2+9l'^2)y^2 + (-6m'^2+6l'^2)xy + (12m'^2+l'^2)x + (-4m'^2+6l'^2)y + 4m'^2 + l'^2 - (m'l')^2  \\\
    & \equiv Ax^2 +By^2+Cxy+Fx+Gy+H=0 
  \end{align*}
$$

For an ellipse to stay ellipse after affine transform, $B^2 − 4AC < 0$ should still hold, see the below theorem.

$$
  (m'^2+9l'^2)^2 - 4(9m'^2+l'^2)(-6m'^2+6l'^2) < 0
$$

[image: Conic Affine Transformations]

Comment: Technically, this is an affine map, not a linear one. Still trying to parse your question...

Comment: Thanks, I am still working on this as well.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Hello, if I substitute the $x', y'$ in the given equation (b), it looks like a non-standard quadratic form with $m', l'$ in the coefficients. In this case, they look liked a non-standard quadratic form, yet, I still not able to see the conditions expression regrading $l,m,l',m'$.

Comment: You mean to require that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ is orthogonal.

Comment: The dot product of column vectors of the matrix does equal to 0, but I did not normalize them. Yes, what I know about affine mapping tells me that the graph still holds the same except for its direction, and I think this called an rotation matrix.

Comment: What it is an "ecllipse" in math jerg?

Answer (score 1):

Since the congruent transformation $T $ can be writed as
$$
\left(\begin{array}{l}
 x^{\prime} \\
 y^{\prime}
\end{array}\right)=\lambda\left(\begin{array}{ll}
 a & b \\
 c & d
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
 x \\
 y
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{l}
 e \\
 f
\end{array}\right),
$$
it is equvalent to
$$
(x',y')=T(x,y)=(\lambda a x+\lambda b y+e ,\lambda c x+\lambda d y+f)
$$
Since  congruent transformation is reversible transformation,then we have
$$
(x,y)=T^{-1}(x',y')=\left ( \frac{dx'-by'-ed+bf}{\lambda(ad-bd)} ,\frac{-cx'+ay'+ec-af}{\lambda(ad-bd)}  \right ) 
$$
Let $F_a(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{l^2}+\frac{y^2}{m^2}  -1$,and denote the set $G_a$ by
$$
G_a=\left \{ (x,y):F_a(x,y)=0 \right \} 
$$
Then,for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
 x\in T(G)&\Longleftrightarrow T^{-1}(x)\in G \\
 &\Longleftrightarrow F_a(T^{-1}(x))=0
\end{aligned}
$$
It follows that $T(G_a)$ can be writes as
$$
T(G_a)=\left \{ (x',y')\in \mathbb{R}^2:\frac{\left ( \frac{dx'-by'-ed+bf}{\lambda(ad-bd)}  \right )^2 }{l^2} +\frac{\left ( \frac{-cx'+ay'+ec-af}{\lambda(ad-bd)}  \right )^2 }{m^2} =1 \right \}
$$
That is to say $T(G_a)$ satisfies the following equation：
$$
 \left ( dx-by-ed+bf \right )^2{m^2} +  \left ( -cx+ay+ec-af  \right ) ^2{l^2} -m^2l^2\lambda^2(ad-bd)^2 =0\quad (*)
$$
We can write $(*)$ as
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 (c^{2} l^{2} +d^{2} m^{2}) x^{2}+(a^{2} l^{2} +b^{2} m^{2}) y^{2}+(-2 b d m^{2} -2 a c l^{2}) x y +(2 e a c l^{2} +2 e b d m^{2} -2 a^{2} f l^{2} -2 b^{2} f^{2}) y+ \\
 (2 b d f m^{2}-2 e c^{2} l^{2} -2 e d^{2} m^{2} +2 a c f l^{2}) x+2 a b d^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} m^{2}-m^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} a^{2} d^{2}-m^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} b^{2} d^{2} \\
 +e^{2} c^{2} l^{2}+e^{2} d^{2} m^{2}-2 e a c f l^{2}-2 e b d f m^{2}+b^{2} f^{2} m^{2}+a^{2} f^{2} l^{2}=0\quad (**)
\end{array}
$$
Let
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 A= c^{2} l^{2} +d^{2} m^{2}\\
 B =-2 b d m^{2} -2 a c l^{2}\\
 C =a^{2} l^{2} +b^{2} m^{2} \\
 D =2 b d f m^{2}-2 e c^{2} l^{2} -2 e d^{2} m^{2} +2 a c f l^{2}\\
 E =2 e a c l^{2} +2 e b d m^{2} -2 a^{2} f l^{2} -2 b^{2} f^{2}\\
 F=2 a b d^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} m^{2}-m^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} a^{2} d^{2}-m^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} b^{2} d^{2} +e^{2} c^{2} l^{2}+e^{2} d^{2} m^{2}-2 e a c f l^{2}-2 e b d f m^{2}+b^{2} f^{2} m^{2}+a^{2} f^{2} l^{2}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $(**)$ can be writed as
$$
A x^{2}+B x y+Cy^{2}+D x+E y+F=0\quad (***)
$$
Let
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
 \Delta & =B^{2}-4 A C \\
 \delta_{1} & =F\left(B^{2}-4 A C\right)+\left(A E^{2}+C D^{2}-B D E\right) \\
 & =F \Delta+\left(A E^{2}+C D^{2}-B D E\right) \\
 \sigma_{1} & =A E^{2}+C D^{2}-B D E \\
 \sigma_{2} & =\sqrt{(A+C)^{2}+\left(B^{2}-4 A C\right)} \\
 x_{0} & =\frac{2 C D-B E}{B^{2}-4 A C} \\
 y_{0} & =\frac{2 A E-B D}{B^{2}-4 A C}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
If $(***)$ is elliptic,it  should satisfy
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 \Delta <0  \\
 (A+C) \cdot\left(F \Delta+\sigma_{1}\right)>0
\end{array}\right.
$$
In addition, the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
 a&b \\
 c&d
\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible matrix,which implies that $ad-bc\ne 0$

Above all, the necessary and sufficient condition of the existence of the affine transformation from $F_a$ to $F_b$ is
$$
   \left\{\begin{array}{l}
\Delta <0  \\
(A+C) \cdot\left(F \Delta+\sigma_{1}\right)>0\\
ad-bc\ne 0\\
A=\frac{1}{l'} \\
B=0\\
C=\frac{1}{m'}\\
D=0\\
E=0\\
F=-1\\ 
\end{array}\right.
$$
i.e.
$$
   \left\{\begin{array}{l}
 ad-bc\ne 0\\
 c^{2} l^{2} +d^{2} m^{2} =\frac{1}{l'} \\
 -2 b d m^{2} -2 a c l^{2}=0\\
 a^{2} l^{2} +b^{2} m^{2}=\frac{1}{m'}\\
 2 b d f m^{2}-2 e c^{2} l^{2} -2 e d^{2} m^{2} +2 a c f l^{2}=0\\
 2 e a c l^{2} +2 e b d m^{2} -2 a^{2} f l^{2} -2 b^{2} f^{2}=0\\
 2 a b d^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} m^{2}-m^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} a^{2} d^{2}-m^{2} l^{2} \lambda^{2} b^{2} d^{2} +e^{2} c^{2} l^{2}+e^{2} d^{2} m^{2}-2 e a c f l^{2}-2 e b d f m^{2}+b^{2} f^{2} m^{2}+a^{2} f^{2} l^{2}+1=0\\ 
\end{array}\right.
$$